# automate postgresql data migration, preferably a fabric task

Tags: postgresql, deployment, data-migration, fabric

My web stack is django/python + postgresql + linux + apache. I use *fabric* to automate the deployment from local to the server. For the deployment automation, I wish I could include data migration from my local database to the corresponding database on the server. Is there a way to do that? I prefer to see the data migration becoming a *fabric* task, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to somehow export the data to a file / files, copy to the target server, and import them. The utilities to do this in Django ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model)) are `dumpdata` and `loaddata`.

So on the local database:

```
django-admin.py dumpdata > mydata.json
```

Then to the server:

```
fabric.api.put('mydata.json','/server/data/dir/')
fabric.api.run('django-admin.py loaddata mydata.json')
```

You should also have a look at [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), which is a database migration tool for Django.

Comment: hmm~ I guess I have to look into them more to figure out a way to streamline these actions.